# How to handle try catch exception when creating an index with python elasticsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, exception, try-catch

I try to print an error if the index is already exist. I use python with Elasticsearch.

```
import time,schedule
import requests
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch 
import sys
import logging
import json
from datetime import datetime

es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch('http:/ip:port',timeout=600)
settings = { "settings": {
                 "number_of_shards":1,
                  'number_of_replicas':0
                 },
      "mappings" : { 
           "document" : {
                "properties":{
                    "geo": {
                       "type": "geo_point"
                            }
                          }
                        } 
                     } 
                  }
try:
 es.indices.create(index = "spacestation", body=settings)
except Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException as es1:
 print('Index already exists!!')
```

But I got following error:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'resource_already_exists_exception', 'index [spacestation/IlVCpABTSYmWVDVrGmTRMA] already exists')
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "__main__.py", line 42, in <module>
except Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException as es1:
AttributeError: type object 'Elasticsearch' has no attribute 'ElasticsearchException'
```

I don't get this error, whether my code is correct or not. I think this is not correct code to print error if already exist the index. Please some one can correct me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change your code to this:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestError
...


try:
  es.indices.create(index = "spacestation", body=settings)
except RequestError as es1:
  print('Index already exists!!')
  sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: I got this error: Traceback (most recent call last):

File "__main__.py", line 42, in <module> except elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError as es1:
NameError: name 'elasticsearch' is not defined

Comment: This isn't come with "Elasticsearch"?

Comment: Yes it's working, thanks, but I've made one mistake when ask the question. Actually I need to print this error and stop the program. With this way I print the error and continues for other steps which is  streaming data. What I need if index already exist print error and stop the program!!

Comment: Thanks, that's what i needed!!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with 8.4.3. For me, the result of es.indices.create is an ObjectApiResponse, with an embedded dict, that may have an 'error' element or an 'acknowledged' :True one. So I need do something like `if 'error' in result: print(result['error'])`. Maybe I'm missing something?